# How can I use the state on an external function?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Can someone explain me how to use the state on the external function?

All I get is:

> Unresolved reference: selectedTab on the composable function contentTabs

```
var selectedTab by remember { mutableStateOf(Tabs.TabContent) }
//...
TabRow(selectedTabIndex = selectedTab.ordinal)
{
    Tab(
        selectedContentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
        unselectedContentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.medium),
        selected = selectedTab.ordinal == Tabs.TabContent.ordinal,
        onClick = { selectedTab = Tabs.TabContent}
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(
                text = Tabs.TabContent.title,
            )
        }
    }
    // More Tabs 
    Tab()
    Tab()
}
```

Here is my enum class:

```
enum class Tabs(
    val title: String
) {
    ContentTabPosts("People"), TabCommunity("Friends")
}
```

Here is my external function:

```
@Composable
fun contentTabs(inputTab : Tabs){
    Tab(
        selected = selectedTab.ordinal == Tabs.inputTab.ordinal,
        onClick = { selectedTab = Tabs.inputTab }
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
        ) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
            Text(
                text = Tabs.inputTab.title,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Just as you the system views do, e.g. `TextField`, you can pass the value and the update callback:

   ```
   @Composable
   fun contentTabs(
       selectedTab: Tabs,
       setSelectedTab: (Tabs) -> Unit,
   ){
       Tab(
           selected = selectedTab.ordinal == Tabs.inputTab.ordinal,
           onClick = { setSelectedTab(Tabs.inputTab) }
       ) {
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   contentTabs(
       selectedTab = selectedTab,
       setSelectedTab = { selectedTab = it }
   )
   ```
2. An other option is passing a mutable state. It's not much recommended as makes testing/previewing less clear, also you need to have a raw state without delegation:

   ```
   @Composable
   fun contentTabs(
       selectedTabState: MutableState<Tabs>,
   ){
       Tab(
           selected = selectedTabState.value.ordinal == Tabs.inputTab.ordinal,
           onClick = { selectedTabState.value = Tabs.inputTab  }
       ) {
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   var selectedTabState = remember { mutableStateOf(Tabs.TabContent) }
   var selectedTab by selectedTabState
   // ...
   contentTabs(selectedTabState)
   ```